# Нужна ли нам метка ttf?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

По метке [ttf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttf) в основном, все вопросы относятся к метке [font](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font). Особой специфики, свойственной именно [ttf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttf) нет -- просто лепят её до кучи.

Так ли она нужна?

Comment: Кто будет возражать против, прошу приводить удачные примеры использования метки [tag:ttf].

Comment: Заодно, хорошо бы синонимизировать метки "шрифт" и "шрифты".

Comment: @Kromster, на счёт "шрифт" и "шрифты" я бы поспорил. Ну например: если я буду задавать вопрос на тему "Как мне сделать такой символ в шрифте?" или "Как мне адаптировать свой шрифт на сайте?" то я задам метку "шрифт". А если я задам "Какую программу лучше использовать для создания шрифтов?" или "Какой шрифт лучше подойдёт на этот сайт?" то я воспользуюсь "шрифты".

Comment: @Kromster, дело в том, что есть метки по самому шрифту (т.е. вопрос именно про его строение или что-то вроде), которые относятся к метке "шрифты", а есть вопросы на тему, как использовать шрифт где-то (т.е. вопрос про то, как использовать шрифт), такие вопросы относятся в "шрифт"

Comment: Какую именно проблему вызывает существование метки [tag:ttf]? Т.е. вот мы потратим время и вырежем эту метку из N старых вопросов - кто получит от этого пользу? "Я люблю чистоту и просто хочу удалять те метки, которые лично мне не нравятся" - плохой аргумент. Их станет проще найти? На них станут чаще приходить из поисковиков? Решения в них станут лучше от удаления метки?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov кажется, надо вбивать это в шаблоны комментариев.